# PHP YII framework Error: Unknown command "webapp"

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to install Yii framework on windows XP in XAMPP. I am getting this error

```
Error: Unknown command "webapp".
```

I am using this command

```
yii webapp ../../myprojct
```

I have set the path as

```
SET PATH=D:\xampp\php
```

I am using the Yii 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `webapp` command anymore in yii2. Creating a project is done with `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic`.
Please refer to the [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html) for instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Download yii2 file from Yii2 Framework website and extract it htdocs.
then open the command prompt, use cd command to map the folder directory and finally use this command to install this

```
htdocs/foldername>php init
```

I hope this will help you, Thank You

Comment: Error occurred `Could not open input file: init`

Comment: are you basic template or advanced template??

Comment: if you are using basic, just follow my step open htdocs/yii foldername/config/web.php in this web.php file you can see 'cookieValidationKey' => 'kalais', here instead of kalais what ever you want you can here and it will work

Comment: Installation through composer is better option.